# Initialize Decorator Variable in Class

Tags: python, python-decorators

I'm working with a decorator within a class that can accept a variable and I'd like to initialize that variable within the class.

Below is an example of what I'm currently working with (which is currently working).

```
_RETRIES = 3

class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, foo):
    self._foo=foo

  @retry.FuzzedIntervalsOnException(num_retries=_RETRIES)
  def my_method(self):
    return some_data
```

However I'd like to change this to accept something like `def __init__(self, foo, retries=3)` to allow clients to decide the number of retries. However implementing this is throwing an undefined variable error.

I'm hoping to get to something like the below, however it seems like the correct answer will be more complicated than this:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self, foo, retries=3):
    self._foo=foo
    self.retries=retries

  @retry.FuzzedIntervalsOnException(num_retries=self.retries)
  def my_method(self):
    return some_data
```

Is there an ideal way to initialize a class variable to be used within a decorator?

Many thanks in advance

EDIT:
For additional information on the retry, below is the initialization.

```
class FuzzedIntervalsOnException(object):
   """Retry on exception 

   args:
     delay: Time delay in seconds for each retry.
     num_retries: Total number of retries.
   """
   def __init__(self, delay, num_retries):
     ...
```

Comment: Can you alter the retry decorator to get `num_retries` from self instead of accepting it in an outer call?

Comment: You can't refer to `self.retries` in the decorator call because that happens at class definition time, but there is no `self` until you instantiate the class.  But you can write `retry` so that it looks at `self` when the decorated function is called if no `num_retries` was given.  Can you give a (possibly sketchy) demonstration of the implementation of `retry` itself?  Right now you don't show anything about how `retry` actually works.

Comment: Ah, that is interesting. Yes I think that is exactly what I'm running into and one of these two solutions seems like it will work. I'll add to my question now to add additional information on the implementation of retry.....

Comment: Also, note that if you do this, your class and decorator will be intertwined in a possibly confusing way.  If you need to specify the number of retries when instantiating, why do you need `retry` as a decorator at all?  Why not just build the retry functionality into the appropriate methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `retry` probably looks something like this:

```
def retry(num_retries=0):
    def decorator(fn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            # ...
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

You want to get `self.retries`, but you won't have a reference to `self` until `wrapper` is called. So the only way to do that is to get `self.retries` inside of `wrapper`. Since you aren't passing any arguments to the decorator, you can also get rid of a layer and do something like this:

```
def retry(fn):
    def wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
        num_retries = self.retries
        # ...
    return wrapper
```

Comment: I was hoping that it wasn't going to be something like this :) but this makes sense. Thanks a lot for your help on this, Brett!